# Get edit item value in RadGrid client-side

Tags: javascript, telerik-grid

i'm looking for somone that can help me on this problem:

i've a Telerik RadGrid in edit-mode, after pressing radgrid's update button i do some checks into a javascript file; i want to check the value in some cells that are in edit mode but i don't know how to see the value. 
I try to explain better with an example: i have some columns editable and some read-only, for the read-only columns i can view the value but for the editable columns i view all the html of the cell and i don't know how to get only the value, here is the code

```
function calculate(dgRDO) {
var grid = $find(dgRDO).get_masterTableView();

var righe = grid.get_editItems();
for (var i = 0; i < righe.length; i++) {
    var row = righe[i];

    //i can view this value, CODART column is ReadOnly
    var codart = grid.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "CODART").innerHTML; 

    //i cannot view only the value but i view the entire html of the cell, PREZZO column        is editable
    var prezzo = grid.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "PREZZO").innerHTML;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

RESPONSE FROM TELERIK (IT WORKS)
In order to easily access RadGrid cells client-side you could use the ClientDataKeyNames property. It should contain the DataField names of the columns that will be accessed on the client. Illustration on extracting key values client-side is available in this article.

A sample function for accessing a column that is added to the ClientDataKeyNames collection would look similar to this:

```
function command(sender, eventArgs) {
var grid = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
var masterTableView = grid.get_masterTableView();
var editItem = masterTableView.get_editItems()[0];

var cellValue = editItem.getDataKeyValue("Quantity");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var prezzo = grid.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "PREZZO").val();
```

Comment: I don't understand the function you mention but i see that's a jquery function and i dont'use jquery in the website i'm working on

Comment: Ok i get it,try this `var prezzo = grid.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "PREZZO").innerText;`